# Android 2.2 deprecates restartPackage but adds another headache

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

Android 2.2 release notes have just been released. ActivityManager.restartPackage method has been deprecated and the description is:

> the previous behavior here is no longer available to applications because it allows them to break other applications by removing their alarms, stopping their services, etc.

Instead 2.2 has given another tool for pesky "task killer" apps by introducing new ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses method.

[More Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29)

Can someone explain whether ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses will kill our scheduled alarms?

If so, deprecating ActivityManager.restartPackage was pointless as "task killer" will now abuse ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses.

Comment: What's more important is the new method above that - isUserAMonkey().

Comment: LOL! I couldn't stop laughing as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made tests with this new killing method : alarms are not killed. services are restarting.

Comment: Woohoo! Take that WinMo era "Task Killer" apps!

How long after being killed do Services restart?

Answer (score 1):

It also appears from my testing that user-visible activities are not closed when this method is called.